# How to pass image to matlab script running in LabVIEW environment

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, labview

I have developed a LabVIEW application where Matlab script is running. I want to pass an image acquired through IMAQ to the Matlab script but the input variable does not have supporting data type (types allowed are real,complex, 1D array, 2D array etc.) but no image data type is available. How to pass it ?

Answer (score 2):

Break out your image channels into uchar 2D arrays using IMAQ (1 for each R, G, B, and Alpha).  Pass those in and either reconstruct it in Matlab or operate on the different channels depending on the algorithm.